# Optional field elements in a typo3 Flexible Content Element

Tags: typo3, typoscript, templavoila

Is it possible to add an optional field element in an FCE(Flexible content element)?
if not is it possible to sustain the mapping of a FCE field element if and only if user input a value for that field in FCE?

And also I want to know how to include a plugin or other FCE‘s inside a FCE.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "optional field". Are you talking about a field that is created for multiple FCEs (e.g. because they all use the same DataStructure XML) but only mapped in some of these FCEs and not needed in others?

Comment: I got a solution. I did map such fields(fields that can be choosen optionally) inside a section mapping so that in the backend I can add them according to my choice.